# Is it possible to embed pages from Sentry.io to another Website?

Tags: sentry

Currently, I have a **Sentry.io** account and push errors to the dashboard interface.

I was wondering if the following is possible:

- Take the pages on the existing **Sentry.io** dashboard
- Embed some of the panels and pages in a page on a custom website
- Errors and interface would appear the same way on the custom website
- Can interact with the interface and errors in the same way in terms of viewing sub-tabs and sub-pages

I'm primarily interested in the:

- **Projects** tab and navigate to subtabs like **Project Details** and individual errors
- **Issues** tab and the ability to search and view errors

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just came across Sentry a few weeks ago. According to the API documentation, it states the ability to GET, PUT/POST, and DELETE data even from Projects. So I think your API will allow you to push alerts to your site and if the site is interactive, you should be able to make changes( e.g. resolve issues) and it will also reflect on Sentry.

Keep in mind that the data coming from the API is unstructured, you might need to streamline what you want to show on your site depending on how your site is designed.

I am not sure if I am able to help in some way. I am also open to learning if you are able to discover how to do it or if I am wrong.